# What brand and model is the hand-held sextant tested on the ISS?

Tags: iss, navigation, orion-spacecraft

Astronaut Alexander Gerst is testing an hand-held sextant on the ISS in the context of the experiment *[Sextant Navigation for Exploration Missions](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/2692.html)*, see [picture](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/iss056e049856.jpg) below.
[image: NASA Image: ISS056E049856 - ESA astronaut Alexander Gerst calibrates and operates the Sextant Navigation device that is testing emergency navigation methods such as stability and star sighting in microgravity for future Orion exploration missions.]

What is the brand and model of the sextant?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a [Celestaire](https://www.celestaire.com/) Astra 2.

Source: viewed image full size.

[image]

According to a conference paper from the 2019 the sextant is an **Astra III**.

The paper is
[HOLT, Greg N.; WOOD, Brandon A. *Sextant Navigation on the International Space Station: A human space exploration demo*. 42nd Annual AAS Guidance, Navigation and Control Conference, Breckenridge, CO. 2019 February 3; AAS 19-06415 pp.](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/20190001296)

The quote is:

> The flight instrument was a Celestaire Astra III Professional hybrid
> brass/aluminum sextant, serial number 1183118.

Comment: According to HOLT, Greg N.; WOOD, Brandon A. _Sextant Navigation on the International Space Station: A Human Space Exploration Demo_. 2019. 42nd ANNUAL AAS GUIDANCE & CONTROL CONFERENCE: "The flight instrument was a Celestaire **Astra III** Professional hybrid brass/aluminum sextant, serial number 1183118"... even if, as you pointed out, it seems to me that the label says "ASTRA II".

Comment: @AlessandroJacopson very interesting! Consider posting that as an answer, or editing it into this answer. That source and info deserves to be saved, and comments can go away.

Comment: Why does it say 2 in the photo?

Comment: @Innovine why does it say 3 in the paper? When it's clearly 2 in the real world. Maybe it's bashed together from different parts.